# .htaccess Issue: JS and CSS Rending index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using a WAMP installation and routing everything through my index.php file. The CSS and JS files in my header get called just fine when I remove the .htaccess file, so the file paths are correct, but once I insert the .htaccess file again Chrometools throws this error upon including my JS file

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

When viewing Chrometool's Network>>Response, it shows the JS file contains the content of everything rendered by the index.php file.

Here's my code
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?_page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?_page=$1&_action=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/?]*)/(.*)$ index.php?_page=$1&_action=$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

I thought the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f was supposed to prevent any rewriting of a file when it's called directly?

### **UPDATE**

I've found the line causing the issue is is the second RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?_page=$1&_action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Because my JS and CSS are stored two directories deep from my project root, the rule is directing the file to my index.php.

Neither of these below commands have any affect until I comment out the RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [NC]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and change this line.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
```

To this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [NC]
```

See of that works for you.

**Edit:**

You need the conditions for all your rules. Rewrite Conditions only applies to the first rule following it. Also you can just have it so if it matches static content, then just not do anything. Try your rules this way.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?_page=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?_page=$1&_action=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/?]*)/(.*)$ index.php?_page=$1&_action=$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but stilll no luck. I've found the problem RewriteRule. I just don't know how to implement a fix yet. I'll update my question